# Regex for Word not have some specific words before

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am Looking for Regex for this result

String = This is Cold Water and this is Hot Water, have some Water.

I want to check whether this String has the word 'Water' which doesn't have these 'Cold' and 'Hot' words before it.

```
String mydata = "This is Cold Water and this is Hot Water, have some Water";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^(Cold|Hot)]\sWater");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        String s = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

But it is resulting a no match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[^(Cold|Hot)]\sWater` pattern matches any char other than `(`, `C`, `o` ... `)`, then a single whitespace and then a `Water` substring. The `[^...]` is a *negated character class*, you can't negate sequences of chars with it.

You may use a regex with a [**negative lookbehind**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The most basic form of it for your case is [`(?<!Cold\s|Hot\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/eNHtSY/1), and you may further customize it.

For example, the `\s` only matches 1 whitespace, and the lookbehind won't work if there are 2 or more whitespaces between `Cold` and `Water` or `Hot` and `Water`. In Java regex, you may use [**limiting quantifiers**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) (see [*Constrained-width Lookbehind*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width)), so you may use `\s{1,10}` to allow the lookbehind to "see" 1 to 10 whitespaces behind.

Another enhancement could be whole word matching, enclose the words with `\b`, [**word boundary construct**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Note that [`Matcher#matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) requires a full string match, you actually want to use [`Matcher#find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--).

Here is an example solution:

```
String mydata = "This is Cold Water and this is Hot Water, have some Water";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(?<!(?:\\bCold\\b|\\bHot\\b)\\s{1,10})Water\\b");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
```

See the [Java online demo](https://ideone.com/MUPSUH).

**Pattern details**

- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!` - start of the negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is:

  - `(?:` - start of a [**non-capturing group**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) matching either of the two alternatives:

    - `\\bCold\\b` - a whole word `Cold`
    - `|` - or
    - `\\bHot\\b` - a whole word `Hot`
  - `)` - end of the non-capturing group
  - `\\s{1,10}` - 1 to 10 whitespaces (you may use `\s` if you are sure there will only be 1 whitespace between the words)
- `)` - end of the lookbehind
- `Water` - the search word
- `\\b` - a word boundary